# setting tab order but it is not working correctly?

Tags: .net, asp.net, html, xhtml

My content page has a master page. In the content page I have specified a tab order, but it is not working correctly. After initial control in content page on pressing tab, control go to some controls that are coming from master page.

I even have seen master page tab order is not set there at all. Any idea please why it is happening? How to correct it?

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the relevant code?

Comment: And have you checked the outputted HTML to make sure that the appropriate tabindexes are there and there aren't any conflicts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where does your tab index start? Try starting at 1. Also, you could assign a set of tab orders for that control, say 10-20 where you don't use those values on the masterpage.